# How can I transfer mp3 files (android and ios) to app to upload to fire_storage using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, mp3

How can I upload a mp3 file from android or ios to upload to app so that the app can upload the mp3 to firebase storage using flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [file_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/file_picker#-readme-tab-):

```dart
File audioFile = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.AUDIO, fileExtension: 'mp3');
```

Then, to upload it to Firebase Storage:

```
firebaseStorage.ref()
    .child(YOUR_MUSIC_FOLDER)
    .child(FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION)
    .putFile(audioFile);
```

Comment: Haven't tried, but file_picker doc says:

`FileType.AUDIO - Will let you pick a single audio file. Opens music on iOS. Note that DRM protected files won't provide a path, null will be returned instead.`

So, yes, it'll work, unless the music file is DRM protected. In that case, it's probably impossible to get access to the file for obvious reasons.

Comment: Impossible? Wow

Comment: Yup. It may not be impossible, but I'm pretty sure Apple would do everything to keep you away from those files. Just imagine Spotify, regardless it's Android or iOS. You get a premium trial and download all your musics. Do you think you should be able to access those music files? Of course no. I'm not aware how they manage to keep the files safe, but they certainly do something about it.

Comment: Not as far as I'm concerned. May I ask you if this is a personal app? If so, there are some ways to get rid of DRM. Google it.

Comment: Just an app that uploads the mp3 files from the user's phone and uploads it to the cloud so the user can stream it from the internet whenever he or she wants

Comment: Nice idea but it's not that simple. It wouldn't work on both Android and iOS. Android doesn't have DRM but you simply cannot access the music files unless the user downloaded them from an external source (not Spotify, YouTube Music and related apps).

Comment: No ideas. I'm sorry.

Comment: I guess my last resort would be to create a website and have the users upload the files from there and load them onto the app

Comment: How did you eventually fix this ? Were you able to upload audio from iOS ?